# Mobile network inactive

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Lava iris x 9 ( ANdroid Version 3.4.67) . Initially the issue was everytime a message popup , Unfortunately,the phone stopped . so in order to fix that issue , i have followed many steps from internet inlcluding clearing cache partition , factory reset , clear cash from setting etc..Now that propblem solved but Network is not selected .Mobile network option is inactive when i go to setting to search mobile network manually.Kinldy help to fix this issue. if you wish to get more infor please feel to ask.

many Thanks
Shinu

Comment: Sorry , not X9 , it is X8

Answer (score 0):

Dial *#*#4636#*#* from your dial pad. you will get a Testing Menu

> Select phone information
>   On the top of the page check for the IMEI is available.
>   scroll down and look for a drop down called " Set preferred network type"
>    select 'WCDMA preferred' or ' GSM only'from the drop down
>   Just below that option you can find a button to toggle radio(Turn on radio / Tunr off radio) ensure the button text is 'Turn off radio' and restart the device.

also consider using the SIM in a different mobile to ensure the SIM is working.

Please Vote if the answer is helped you